# Convert Utf8 to Unicode

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I have a text file. I should convert it to Utf8. After converting, all the numbers in the file are converted to question marks. For example 1380 is converted to 4 question marks like this: '????'. 
I'm using delphi 2009.

This is my code for converting:

```
RichEdit1.Lines.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName,TEncoding.UTF8);
```

How can i correct this conversion?

Comment: This is not a "conversion". You're telling the `RichEdit.Lines` that it should expect a UTF8-encoded text file, but apparently not providing one. You need to open the file with the proper encoding (which you don't mention), convert it to UTF8, and then assign that to the `RichEdit.Lines` property. Since you didn't mention what encoding the text file is actually in, I can't make any suggestions about how to convert it to UTF8. Can you edit your question to provide the missing information about what the actual encoding of the text file is on disk? Thanks.

Comment: The existing file is in unicode format . i want to open the file in my application and fill some memo and richedit by some character which are in the file . my file has English character,Persian character and some numeric value with some symbols.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `TEncoding.Unicode` if your file is in UTF-16LE ("Unicode") format.
Or you should convert your file to UTF-8 before loading it into RichEdit.